# Use a regular expression to extract text within parentheses and the instance it appears

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net, string, visual-studio-2010

**Edit**: I made things more confusing then they should have been. Here is what I need to do.

I have three textboxes

In my program the users type `(this) is (this)` into the first textbox.

When a button is pressed I need to extract the first string in brackets and put it in textbox2 and then extract the text from the second string in brackets and put it in textbox3. How do I do this?

**Edit**: I am now using David's suggestion, but it is not returning the value. This is how I am using it:

```
     Dim expression As New Regex("\((.*)\)\s*is\s*\((.*)\)")
     ' expression = "\((.*)\)\s*is\s*\((.*)\)"
         Dim matches As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(CurrentInstruction, expression.ToString())
          MessageBox.Show(matches.Item(0).ToString() & "" & matches.Item(1).ToString())
```

This is what I am typing:

```
if ComparePixelColor (25,15) is (27) = true then
```

Comment: Regular expressions can be used to do this, but it can be tricky to write them, and to learn the API for getting the matched values from the RegEx.

The best method to use may depend on how the rest of your command parser works.

For example, do you already have code that will strip off the prefix of the command?  Is the whole command structured, which may make parsing out the relevant part easier.  Is the input already validated and guaranteed to be syntactically correct?

Comment: If you share the code context, or just the part of the string that would actually need to be parsed, you will make it easier for people to give you an effective answer.

Comment: I have updated the question as it was way more confusing then it should of been. Hopefully someone knows how to do this.

Comment: I am sorry, but you say the users type `(this) is (this)` yet you enter `if ComparePixelColor (25,15) is (27) = true then`. Please describe what you are trying to do?

Comment: Please don't rewrite your entire question. If you do that then the answers and comments you have had no longer make sense. It is better to rephrase your problem and post a new question

Comment: Yes I will do that next time. Last time I did that I had people on my case for reposting a similar question. I never know what the right thing to do here is. Anyways I changed the question because I included more details then I should of causing alot of confusion on what I was trying to do. It is solved now though. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple regex should match the two values within the parenthesis. If you user input has the form (x) is (y):

```
Dim matches As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(userInput, "\((.*)\)\s*is\s*\((.*)\)")
```

matches.Item(0) should contain the value of x and matches.Item(1) should contain y. If matches.Count is equal to 0, then the userInput didn't match the expression. Note this includes any characters within the brackets.

For example, user input is:

```
(25,15) is (27)
```

The two matches will be "25,15" and "27" respectively.

Comment: I think this is kind of what I need. The only thing is both items in the () are going to be all integers. I am trying to pull the first item in the (where xy is) and the second item in the (where color is).

Comment: Okay so maybe you can modify your question again show a sample input and what you expect to capture.

Comment: Yes because the other commands were confusing people so i figure if I use a simpler example it will be easier for others to answer , all I need to do is get the values between the parenthesis and return each result as its own string instead of returning one string for both results. I dont actually need to use the regex to compare anything.

Comment: I will be using something else to compare whether the values are a match, first I need to just get the values.

Comment: Okay, I've updated my answer. I think this is what you are after.

Comment: This is a better regular expression than the one I gave you, but I was trying to keep it simple, as some people find maintaining or updating regular expressions very... erm... confusing.  I wrote a utility program just to make testing them easy, because they are a pain.

Comment: If you ever want a good resource for checking or writing a regex, try this: http://rubular.com. It uses Ruby, but it works just fine for any language.

Comment: Thanks David, that works great, I copied that other regex into my program because I will use it later on for something else.

Comment: Thanks again I would spend alot less time looking for help if I could write good regex. That helps.

Comment: Hi david. I have on question, how do I add a wildcard to it so the text could have any words before the () is () and any after. Example: this () is () this ....I still need to only find the matches like we had before but I just need to fix the regex because the string could have text before and after. I have a different way of finding the other text so I just need a wildcard.

Comment: You don't need to change the regex for this. With a regex you can specify the start and the end of the line with ^ and $. In this case I didn't do either, assuming that you would have text before and after.

Comment: Oops I will add it to the question I think I may be using it wrong.

Comment: You have put a leading * in the regex which won't work. You don't need to specify this at the start or the end. What happens when you use the one you have commented out? And if it's not working, post what you are typing into the box in the first place.

Comment: Yes sorry I added that before you told me I did not need the wildcard. I removed it and same issue. I have added what I am typing.

Comment: Hey, that string definitely works with that regex. You can try it out here: http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx

Is there any reason you are putting the string into a new RegEx object and then converting it back to a string?

Comment: yes for some reason if I use it like this then it says I am using it wrong Regex.Matches(CurrentInstruction, expression)

Comment: I think you should start a new question and show your code and input. There is clear confusion if your chosen answer has a total of -1 votes!

Answer (score 1):

This regular expression will get you every set of substrings starting with an open paren and ending with a closed paren:

```
 \([^)]*\)
```

While you didn't ask, I suspect you will want to parse the color parameter in the second parenthesized group.

This basic code demonstrates extracting the parenthesized groups with the regular expression.

```
dim paren as new RegEx("\([^)]*\)")
dim command as string = "Prefix (123, 45) if (blue)"

dim matches as MatchCollection

matches = paren.Matches(command)

matches.Dump()

dim m as Match

for each m in matches
   Console.WriteLine("M='{0}'", m)
next
```

Once you have a string containing just "(123, 45)" or similar, it is very easy to break down.

Use substring to get rid of the parenthes, split on comma, and take the values.

---

However, to illustrate, and if you just want the first group (which is how your question read when I was writing this answer for you), this will work:

```
dim paren as new RegEx("\([^)]*\)")
dim command as string = "Prefix (123, 45) if (blue)"

dim matches as MatchCollection
dim m as Match

m = paren.Match(command)

dim ms as string = m.Value

ms = ms.Substring(1, ms.Length -2) ' Take off the parens

dim parts as string() = ms.Split(",")

dim x as string = parts(0).Trim()
dim y as string = parts(1).Trim()
```

I strongly recommend the free linqpad

http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.linqpad.net%2F&ei=SPauUM3oGK640gGNroGYAg&usg=AFQjCNFw-ZpPkP4je7u9udiur5Wg5us7tQ

to experiment quickly with code and learn.  That is how I did this VB code for you, even though I usually write .Net stuff in C#.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot that I don't understand here. First of all, what do your users actually type? And what values is it that you want to extract?

Secondly, if something like `if CompareThese` is part of the input then it sounds like they are writing a program, with tight syntax, case-sensitivity and language words. If so then that must be part of a language parser that is way beyond the scope of your question. Otherwise, what exactly can they type?

Even beyond that, I wonder whether the parentheses are part of what is typed in, or do they just mark the place of a value in the text of your question?

To answer you question, you can extract `x` and `y` using just `[0-9]+` if they are integers. I cannot tell what `colour` might be

Comment: I have updated the question as it was way more confusing then it should of been. Hopefully someone knows how to do this.